# Unable to compile libfreefare

Tags: raspbian, nfc

I am attempting to compile libfreefare on raspberry pi, a spinoff from nfc-tools
https://code.google.com/p/libfreefare/

When I follow the install instructions, and try to configure it with `./configure --prefix=/usr` it fails with the following message;

```
....... [skipping to end] ........
checking byteswap.h usability... yes
checking byteswap.h presence... yes
checking for byteswap.h... yes
checking for DES_ecb_encrypt in -lcrypto... no
configure: error: Cannot find libcrypto.
```

I have tried searching for this on google but cant figure out how to either a) install it or b) reconfigure my raspberry pi to make it work.

How do I get the compile script to find libcrypto?

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer, here is the solution for anyone that is missing libcrypto

`sudo apt-get install libssl-dev`